# Salesforce cpq - when re-activating order, the contracts won't be generated again

Tags: cpq

In Salesforce cpq, when we click the contracted button in order, the related contract is automatically generated. This is a out of box feature provided by Salesforce cpq.

We have created a functionality to deactivate the order which deletes all the related contracts and subscriptions and then deactivate the order and untick the contracted button in order.

However, when we re-tick the contracted button again, the contracts are generated again. Is there any walk around for that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The entire purpose of checking the contracted checkbox is to generate a contract. You can just leave the contracted checkbox checked when you delete the contract and avoid this issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a checkbox field at Order object and make it `true` when first time it is contracted.

After that, create a validation rule and verify this value and stop creating contracts again.